# Can't get rid of LNK 2019 error in Dll

Tags: c++, dll, constructor, hyperlink

I keep getting link 2019 errors on this ctor,ctor-copy ctor-assignment code that works in other projects with no errors.  I am trying to include it in a plain DLL generated with the MFC support  option checked.  I'm in VS2010.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Name.h"

CNameBase::CNameBase()
{

    IsGlobal = false;
    UseShortName = true;
    m_ShortName = NO_NAME_ID ;
    m_Description = "";
    pMe = this;

}

CNameBase::CNameBase( const CNameBase& ref )
{
    m_Description = ref.m_Description;
    IsGlobal = ref.IsGlobal;
    m_LongName = ref.m_LongName;
    m_ShortName = ref.m_ShortName;
    UseShortName = ref.UseShortName;
    pMe = ref.pMe;
}

CNameBase& CNameBase::operator=( const CNameBase& ref )
{
    m_Description = ref.m_Description;
    IsGlobal = ref.IsGlobal;
    m_LongName = ref.m_LongName;
    m_ShortName = ref.m_ShortName;
    UseShortName = ref.UseShortName;
    pMe = ref.pMe;
    return *this;
}
```

The link errors are:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CNameBase::CNameBase(void)" (??0CNameBase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CName::CName(void)" (??0CName@@QAE@XZ)

1>clayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CNameBase::CNameBase(class CNameBase const &)" (??0CNameBase@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CName::CName(class CName const &)" (??0CName@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)

1>clayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class CNameBase & __thiscall CNameBase::operator=(class CNameBase const &)" (??4CNameBase@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class CName & __thiscall CName::operator=(class CName const &)" (??4CName@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)

1>C:\devt\hftappb\Debug\CLayer.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

The funny thing is this code works and has worked.  The Ctors do what they're supporsed to do and have been in other solution.  I stick the class in this file and suddenly get these errors that I am having dififculty resolving.  I've compared project settings between this project and projects I know this code works in.  What else could be causing this?

Comment: You *do* build with the source file?

Comment: Hmm, why is there a #pragma once in a .cpp file?

Comment: Yes.  All code is in source.  No importing of libs or anything like that

Comment: Hans you scared me there for a minute.  I was trying anything and hadn't taken it out.  Took it out, same result.

Comment: I mean, the actual source file is in the project and is being built? For example, if you make a small change in the shown source file and rebuild, will the source file be compiled?

Comment: Yes, this is full source in the project aside from a couple includes that are in different projects in the same solution.  If I make a change everything gets rebuilt.  But let me try that..a full rebuild...same result

Comment: You have to `__declspec(dllexport)` your class for it to be usable outside the DLL. I am assuming you get linker errors for a project that uses this DLL - otherwise there is no reason the linker could complain.

Comment: Tibo, thanks for your thoughts.  This particular class is a support class for code in exported code.  I don't want to export it so I just stuck it in the Dll h and cpp as regular code.  Could the compiler think it wants to export the code or do all functions in the file need __declspec?

Comment: BTW this code gets #included into the Dll.

Comment: You need the __declspec thing only for classes (or functions), not for methods. Besides you don't need it if you are not exporting the class, i.e. if as you say it's only a internal helper. Now, you said you moved the code - this has to have had side effects. Do you use namespaces? Do you have bad karma? What is `clayer.cpp`: the .cpp you've shown, or part of the same project? Or part of another one?

Comment: The code that references the CName class is in a class itself.  I just moved the class (call it class Cmd) into the clayer project.  Got everything else to build except these link errors. In this particular project, there were other errors I could fix with type differences that didn't show up in other projects.  I verified the warning levels between the two projects are the same.  There are a couple includes at the top that pull in type information.  But those types check out OK during the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for responding to my question.  The question took the better part of a day to resolve but I wanted to share the answer with others since it can happen to anyone.  The solution to the problem wasn't any code, it was a configuration issue.  In VS2010, apparently, ALL files that your project references must be in the list of files that appear with the project in the Solution Explorer.  I am not privy to the underlying architecture so I can't answer why this is required.  On the surface, there's NO reason for it.  If there are files #included into a project either explicity or implicitly through the Project paths and whose functions I reference from files that are included in the Project's list of files in Solution Explorer, functions in those files should be able to reference functions in files that aren't included in the project filelist in Sol Exp.

The rules for #include and other rules are convoluted enough in C++ without MSFT adding their layers of confusion. These types of errors would be easily prevented with better error reporting and/or UI management.

The rules I've learned are this
1. Never make more than 1 copy of the same file in the entire solution.  Multiple copies of the same file are hard to keep symchronized and lead to confusion as to which one is being used.
2. All files being used in a project must be listed in that project but rule 1 should be respected.

```
Steps (approximate)
1. Create a project
2. Create a .h and .cpp with global functions (or in a class doesn't matter)
3. In the same parent directory as project 1, create project 2  There should be two project directories underneath one parent
4. In project 2 in File Explorer, create a subfolder called Common
5. Create a .h and .cpp in that folder and create a simple function that returns a value
6. Add those files to project 2 in Solution Explorer
7. In Project 1, in the .cpp, create a function that #includes the file for project 2 and calls that function in that file.
8. The compiler generates a 2019 and 2001 unresolved external link error.  What it should do is report that those files are required to be in your project's file list.
```

Answer (score 0):

The cpp file that holds the implementation of the 3 functions doesn't compile/link into the exe/dll.

If you're using C++ namespaces, you need to make sure that both header and cpp use it. The namespace is part of the class name.

Comment: Not using namespaces here, including the std namespace.  I use std::string to avoid them.